# ValueError at logout, logout didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, logout

Got the following error on pressing Logout Button with the code at bottom-

ValueError at /logout
The view app.views.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: **GET**
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout

Django Version: 3.0.8

Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
The view app.views.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

my code is

```
def logout(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('login')
```

my html is

```
<li class="nav-item mr-3">
                <form id="logout" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type ="hidden">
                </form>
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout'%}" onclick="javacript:document.getElementById('logout').submit()">
                    Logout
                </a>   
            </li>
```

Comment: it is obvious you have <a> tag with href inside form which is being triggered instead of form

Comment: Which version of Django you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
def logout(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('login')
```

No need for explicit `redirect`, as `auth.logout` can handle redirection after logout. Just set `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "my_url"` in settings.py

Alternatively, Same can be achieve in `urls.py` as well if you are using Django 2.2.x or higher, in `urls.py` import

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
```

then add following path in urlpatterns,

```
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page=settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL), name='logout'),
```

Then you don't need any code in your views.py